# How to pass Controller variables to an EventListener in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig, event-listener

I'm bored of writing this at the end of every action in Symfony2:

```
return $this->render('Project:Bundle:view.twig', array(
                                     'foo' => 1,
                                     'bar' => 2
                                 ));
```

So I've attempted to hook into the request lifecycle just after an action has been run, in order to save myself some typing. I want to be able to do something similar to this in my controller instead:

```
$this->params = array(
    'foo' => 1,
    'bar' => 2
);
```

A listener would then pass the params to the render, and auto-detect the template using the action name. I realise I need to use Event Listeners to achieve this, but I can't seem to hook into the lifecycle at the right time...

- **kernel.controller** is good, because I can get at the controller, but it's before the action has been run, so $this->params won't be set
- **kernel.response** is after the action has run, but I can't seem to get at the controller itself from here

FYI - I've got a Zend background, and this is (obv) my first time using Symfony2... If I'm approaching this problem in entirely the wrong manner, shout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, you can use the `@Template()` annotation and return an array:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FooBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class BarController
{
    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function bazAction()
    {
        return array(
            'some_value' => $someValue;
        );
    }
}
```

The annotation tells it to look for the view in the default location based on bundle, controller and action name (in this case, `AcmeFooBundle:Bar:baz.html.twig`).

Comment: Well, if that isn't exactly what I'm after! Thanks!